# How Cobol dynamic call works using group as program identifier?

Tags: call, cobol, microfocus

I have the following call statement :

```
038060     CALL        PROG USING
038070                 DFH
038080                 L000
038090                 ZONE-E
038100                 ZONE-S.
```

This call is dynamic and use **PROG**.

**PROG** is a group defined as :

```
018630 01                 XX00.
018640        10          PROG.
018650         15         XX00-S06  PICTURE X(6)
018660                         VALUE  SPACE.
018670         15         XX00-S02  PICTURE X(2)
018680                         VALUE  SPACE.
018690        10          XX00-S92  PICTURE 9(02)
018700                         VALUE  ZERO.
018710        10          XX00-S91  PICTURE 9(1)
018720                         VALUE  ZERO.
018730        10          XX00-S9Z PICTURE 9(1)
018740                         VALUE  ZERO.
018750        10          XX00-9B0 PICTURE X(05)
018760                         VALUE  SPACE.
018770        10          XX00-0B0 PICTURE X(02)
018780                         VALUE  SPACE.
018790        10          XX00-BB1 PICTURE X(01)
018800                         VALUE  SPACE.
018810        10          XX00-SFN PICTURE X(07)
I cut here but there is a lot of field after...
```

It seems that actual progname to use is stored in :

> XX00-S06

and

> XX00-S02

I've also other cases where the name is on 3 or 4 fields, and the progname length is not always 8.

So my question is **how Cobol know where to pick the good program name in the group? What are the resolution rules?**

**Configuration** : I use Microfocus Net Express compiler and the environment is UniKix.

Comment: The question doesn't even acknowledge that `CALL literal` can be a dynamic CALL, or recognised that it is documented in the compiler manuals for the product in question, potentially with differences from vendor to vendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic call rules in COBOL are fairly simple. Given something like:

```
    CALL WS-NAME USING...
```

COBOL will resolve the program name currently stored in `WS-NAME` against the load module libraries
available to it based on
a linear search. The first matching load module entry point name that matches `WS-NAME` is used.

It doesn't matter how complex, or simple, the definition of `WS-NAME` is. The total length used for the name
is whatever the length of `WS-NAME` is. For example:

```
   01 WS-NAME.
      05 WS-NAME-FIRST-PART     PIC X(3).
      05 WS-NAME-MIDDLE-PART    PIC X(2).
      05 WS-NAME-LAST-PART      PIC X(3).
```

`WS-NAME` is composed of 3 subordinate fields giving a total of 8 characters. You can populate these individually or just move
something into `WS-NAME` as a whole. If the length of `WS-NAME` is less than 8 characters, the trailing characters will be
set to spaces on any receiving field. For example:

```
  01 WS-SHORT-NAME.
     05 WS-SHORT-NAME-FIRST-PART          PIC X(4) VALUE 'AAAA'.
     05 WS-SHORT-NAME-LAST-PART           PIC X(2) VALUE 'BB'.
```

Here `WS-SHORT-NAME` is only 6 characters long. `MOVING WS-SHORT-NAME` to any longer `PIC X` type variable as in:

```
  MOVE WS-SHORT-NAME TO WS-NAME
```

Will result in WS-NAME taking on the value 'AAAABB<strike>bb</strike>' (note the two trailing spaces). During libary search
for a matching entry point name, the trailing spaces are not significant so on the CALL statement you could use
either:

```
  CALL WS-NAME
```

or

```
  CALL-WS-SHORT-NAME
```

And they will resolve to the same entry point.

I am not sure what the length rules are for MicroFocus COBOL but, for IBM z/os dynamically called
program names cannot exceed 8 characters (if they do, the name is truncated to 8 characters).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! For Microfocus I don't find limit, so I think it just take the whole group.

Answer (score 1):

I will add little more to NeilB with specific information about Micro Focus COBOL.

fyi: PROGRAM-ID, ENTRY-POINTS are restricted to 30-31 characters (check your "System Limits and Programming Restrictions" section in the docs).